# Python3 multiprocessing child processes sometimes stuck in futex_wait_queue_me on first network access

Tags: python-3.x, linux, multiprocessing, locking

I have a master program written in Python3.9 that will eventually load and control modules using multiprocessing.

The modules will do some short lived work and terminate. Sometimes, the module will start to run (emitting debug logs to stdout), but get stuck on the first network access (usually a requests call, but IIRC there have been failures in a module that does performs a pymssql connect first).

The child process running the module will hang in futex_wait_queue_me forever, and cannot be killed with SIGTERM; SIGKILL is necessary to stop the process. The stack shows

```
cat /proc/12345/stack
 <0>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xb6/0x110
[<0>] futex_wait+0xe9/0x240
[<0>] do_futex+0x174/0xbc0
[<0>] __x64_sys_futex+0x146/0x1c0
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x33/0x80
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

I suspected some lock on handles inherited from the parent control process, so I added os.closerange(3,100) to close all handles except for stdin/stdout/stderr, but this didn't help.

```py
def startSub(params, config):
  sub=Process(target=SubModule, args=(params, config))
  sub.daemon=True
  sub.start()
  return sub
  # sub will run independently until it terminates; no IPC, only sub.is_alive() from here

class SubModule:
  def __init__(self, params, config):
    os.closerange(3,100)
    setproctitle("Submodule")                    # identify this process
    log.debug("Starting stuff")                  # this will show up correctly
    result=requests.get("https://somewhere.org") # sometimes this will not come back
    log.debug("came back from requests")         #
```

The program is running in a python3.9-slim-bullseye container. After adding gdb to the container, I was able to capture a backtrace of the problem in the original container:

```
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
  <built-in method getaddrinfo of module object at remote 0x7f4fd9634350>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 329, in create_connection
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 681, in _new_conn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1467, in urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 951, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 1310, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
```

So apparently, the program is stuck at _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0):

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f4fd9c19d66 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f4fd9cb4bed in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f4fd9cb4fcb in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f4fd9cb3955 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f4fd9cb474b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f4fd9cb48d3 in __resolv_context_get () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007f4fd9ca54e9 in gethostbyname2_r () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x00007f4fd9c7cfac in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#8  0x00007f4fd9c7db25 in getaddrinfo () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#9  0x0000000000615b1e in socket_getaddrinfo (self=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, kwargs=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/socketmodule.c:6574
#10 0x000000000065e4fd in cfunction_call (func=<built-in method getaddrinfo of module object at remote 0x7f4fd9634350>, args=<optimized out>, kwargs=<optimized out>)
    at ../Objects/methodobject.c:539
```

Which leaves me clueless for now.
Anybody who can shed some light on what's happening?

NB: This is apparently *not* the issue as described here https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-deadlock-your-python-with-getaddrinfo, since I'm not stuck in a lock waiting to call libc's getaddrinfo(), but the lock happens deep down in getaddrinfo().

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found what's happening:
While python does quite a good job cleaning up thread related stuff in the child process after forking, libc itself does not. So a subprocess might inherit thread safety locks that never get unlocked.
Fix is to avoid forking from threaded applications alltogether, by switching multiprocessing's start method to spawn:

```py
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
set_start_method("spawn")
```

Comment: It seems has been set in my case. `RuntimeError: context has already been set`